# Generating nHibernate cfg file from Configuration instance

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Is there any way for me to generate an nHibernate configuration file from a Configuration instance (that has been already configured by some external code?). I'm looking for an easy way to mimic this external code with a static XML file?

(I guess similar to the "ExportTo" method that Fluent nHibernate has for fluent mappings - but acting on the resulting Configuration object instead).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that easily.

What *can* be done (and is common) is *binary* serialization of the configuration. Check http://github.com/ayende/Effectus/blob/master/Effectus/Infrastructure/BootStrapper.cs

Comment: Thanks Diego, that was close enough to what I needed! :)